# How to reset VM of Google Cloud SDK?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am having a problem of creating database in Google Cloud SDK using provided scripts in a course and would like to reset the VM (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). However, on the Google Cloud SDK documentation, I only found [how to uninstall SDK from computer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk), which I believe is different from resetting the VM (which is on the cloud). Are these the same thing? If not, how can I reset the VM? I also have direct SSH connection with VM, can I reset using SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation provided a detailed explanation of how to reset a VM:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#resetting_an_instance

You can either use the web console, or use the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances reset VM_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to re-run `gcloud compute firewall` or `gcloud compute instances create`, or do these settings still exist in the VM?

Comment: this only affects the instance. It's a RESET, not remove/destroy. No need to recreate the instance. Firewall is still there too.